# Beamer tikz: Draw two boxes containing texts with fancy arrow pointing from one to another

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want two boxes containing text that their lengths are determined by length(s) of row(s) of texts before line break `\\` and breaths by the number of rows.

I also need a fancy arrow containing text also pointing from one arrow to another.

**Illustration of what I whant**
[image: Sketch of what I want]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A version where the node width is determined by the content, as required, and the arrow carries some text.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.arrows,shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some picture}
\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5em,
        nodes={draw,fill=white,blur shadow},
        box/.style={align=left,inner sep=1ex},
        marrow/.style={single arrow,
              single arrow head extend=2mm,
              execute at begin node={\strut}}]
   \node (A) [box] {Some text\\ more text };
   \node (B) [marrow, right=of A]{text};
   \node (C) [box, right=of B] {Some text\\ more text};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{my image \dots}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm,
box/.style = {draw, text width=0.3*\linewidth},
arr/.style = {single arrow, draw, 
              single arrow head extend=2mm,
              node contents={\phantom{arrow}}}
                    ]
\node (n1) [box] {Text, text, text, text, text, text };
\node (n2) [arr, right=of n1];
\node (n1) [box, right=of n2] {Text, text, text, text, text, text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```